# OpenCV: using GraphCutSeamFinder to stitch two images with best seam

Tags: python, opencv, image-stitching

I have been making an automatic panorama stitcher in python and now stuck in seam finding step.
Following is my code in the structure which I understood from opencv docs.

```
im1 = cv2.imread('n3/0.jpg')
im2 = cv2.imread('n3/5.jpg')

c1 = [0,0]
c2 = [5,130] #calculated using ORB feature matching

mask1 = np.full(im1.shape[:2], 255)
mask2 = np.full(im2.shape[:2], 255)

finder = cv2.detail_GraphCutSeamFinder("COST_COLOR_GRAD")
finder.find([im1, im2], [c1, c2], [mask1, mask2])
```

This gives the following error which is not understandable by me.

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/detail/gcgraph.hpp:121: error: (-215:Assertion failed) w>=0 && revw>=0 in function 'addEdges'

This is the simplest example which I can set up, please help on what I am doing wrong.

AS requested, I am adding input images

`n3/0.jpg`
[image: n3/0.jpg]

`n3/5.jpg`
[image: n3/5.jpg]

**UPADTE**

By using another method I have achieved the desired result, but I still want to use the inbuilt function. Please help

`resultant image after using the masks`
[image: resultant image after using the masks]

Comment: Have the images been loaded properly?

Comment: yes, I have seen them using `cv2.imshow`, They are properly loaded

Comment: @Cybersupernova can you please post the input images in your question?

Comment: @Bilal sure i have updated the question

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error but the program kept terminating without giving an output or an error. I found an alternate implementation of image stitching. Maybe it can help you out. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/17/image-stitching-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: @AhsanGoheer thanks for the help but I have been on that blog. The program should exit only since the masks will be modified and used by another function. But you are pointing towards system-dependent bug, maybe I will try on some other machines.

Comment: @Cybersupernova Yeah I guess you're right. I just renamed the images before using the code that you have given above. Windows does not support the naming scheme you used. It didn't give me the error.

Comment: @Cybersupernova, Did you resolve the problem?

Comment: no, but I just used another approach

Answer (score 1):

The Python bindings of Graph Cut Seam Finder are corrupted at the moment. Please monitor [this PR](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/22329) with a possible fix. I hope that it'll get merged soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
mask1 = np.full(bl.shape[:2], 255, dtype=np.uint8)

mask2 = np.full(br.shape[:2], 255, dtype=np.uint8)
```

This works for me. I used https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching . And find out that the type is `np.uint8`. If remove '`dtype=np.uint8`', the masks will not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your input image 'im1' and 'im2' should be normalized to [0,1] which is float type. By doing this, the error can be removed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact error, which I solved by converting my each input image data type to float32.

```
dataset = dataset.astype(np.float32)
```

And then carry on as usual:

```
finder = cv2.detail_GraphCutSeamFinder("COST_COLOR")
seam_masks = finder.find(datasets, corners, masks)
```